# Delete duplicate features with identic geometry based on attribute with QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, duplication

I have a vector layer containing landmark buildings in Stockholm. Each landmark building consists out of several features with the same KOM_ID but with different Z-values. When rasterizing this shape the building height (z-value) gets wrong due to the fact that multiple features with the same geometry overlap. For example the selected area below consists out of two features, one 61 and the other 37 meters above sea level. When rasterizing the z-value becomes 37, but only the value 61 is correct/relevant for me.

How can I "clean-up" this shape to get rid of duplicate overlapping features, keeping only the feature with the highest z-value (z-value marked with red circles below and named "hojd")

Download the shapefile [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwFHJFrNX33hNW84YXdHNkcxRHM/view?usp=sharing).

[image]

Comment: do you know Raster Calculator ? If your result is a Raster, you can perform a new analysis to get output with the  highest z-value for each cell.

Comment: I've added the shape file above. The problem is that when I rasterize the file, only the value 37 gets written to the raster, not 61. So I figured I need to solve this while still in vector?

Comment: ok you are right. You have to send all your file with the name globen to share your shapefile (.dbf, shx, prj ...)

Comment: No, actually you are right. SAGA GIS rasterize function lets you decide what to do if multiple values where found. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: great to know, happy to know I helped you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it using SAGA GIS rasterize function that lets you decide what to do if multiple values where found. Then I chose to keep the maximum value.